# View Controller Presentation Warning - Presenting two at the same time

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am getting this warning when I try to present a second VC modally.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <RCTAddCardViewController: 0x1f5b21e0> on <IRSlidingSplitViewController: 0x1f538140> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
UIViewController *pvc = [self presentingViewController];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    RCTAddCardViewController *vc = [[RCTAddCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [pvc presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

I shouldn't be getting the error bc it's being presented inside the completion handler of the first VC's dismissal. Anyone know a way to get this to go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on `self`, if you were also presenting  a view controller by `self`, that view controller would be dismissed (so `pvc` would still be presenting `self`). If that's not the issue, I guess it only counts the presentation complete after the completion block has returned.

One  workaround would be to create a `-myPresentViewController:` method, and use use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentViewController:) withObject:vc afterDelay:0.001]
```

inside the block

Comment: For some reason when I try `po pvc` in the debugger I get a nil

Comment: Do you also get nil if you add `NSLog(@"%@", pvc)` after `UIViewController *pvc = [self presentingViewController];` ?

Comment: That one works. Interestingly `po pvc` has started not being nil either.

Comment: I fixed it by using a variation of your technique. Instead of `performSelector:` I went straight into `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`.

Comment: The reason po pvc was returning nil was probably because of some compiler optimization somehow deferring that line of code. When you're using pvc with NSLog in the next line, it needs pvc right away, so it can't do the deferring any more.